# How to have recursive tree genealogy in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, tree, genealogy

I'm making tree genealogy in symfony.

I have two entities :

```
User: id    firstname    partner    
       1    Julien       Anne      
       2    Eric         Marie    

Relation: id    family_id    child
          1     1            Manon 
          2     1            Camille
          3     2            Julie
```

I would like to have recursive tree genealogy like child can have partner and can have children but I don't know how to do that.

Shoud I need an other entity ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about your data design before you start trying to apply it to a particular programming environment.

Think about separating (all) People from (all) Relationships.

Person:
Name, Id (and any other demographics you want to store, e.g. date of birth)

Relationship:
Id1, Id2, Relationship Type

Relationship Type might be Partner, Child.

Then you can give a child a partner, or a child of their own, without trouble.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: I just have question. How can relate id1 and id2 from Person ?

Comment: Join it twice (assuming we're talking sql here), so (say) select p1.name, p2.name, r.reltype from relationships r join people p1 on r.id1=p1.id join people p2 on r.id2=p2.id